# Is there an established single-letter abbreviation for Pokemon energy types?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am playing Pokemon Go and want to keep a note of the types of my Pokemon and their attacks in the name field. I have found unofficial suggestions like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vcydv/heres_3_nickname_formats_to_display_as_many_stats/), but this is too much information for me, and the type abbreviations here are two-letter.

So my question is - is there an established one-letter system of abbreviations for Pokemon energy types, akin to the one used in the Magic TCG for the five mana types (WUBRG)?

Comment: I'd be suprised if there is one. There are 4 types that start with an `F`. The type that'd be abbreviated with `F` can be easily mistaken with one of the other three, unlike the MTG types

Comment: So I've had one upvote and two downvotes but no explanation of the downvotes. Would anyone care to explain what is bad about the question so that I could improve it?

Comment: @Mathias711 MTG has Blue and Black, which both start with a B. Not sure how that's any different from Pokémon's several F-types, other than higher proportion.

Comment: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/ could propably answer the question based on the TCG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an established system in the TCG, which has fewer types: *(corresponding video game types)*

[**C**]olorless *(Normal, Flying, older cards also Dragon)*
[**F**]ighting *(Fighting, Rock, Ground)*
[**L**]ightning *(Electric)*
[**G**]rass *(Grass, Bug, older cards also Poison)*
[**P**]sychic *(Psychic, Ghost, Poison)*
[**M**]etal *(Steel)*
[**W**]ater *(Water, Ice)*
[**D**]arkness *(Dark)*
Fi[**R**]e *(Fire)*
Drago[**N**] *(Dragon)*
Fair[**Y**] *(Fairy)*

While there's no widely agreed upon similar system for the full type list we find in the video games (mainly because there's no use for it outside of *Pokémon Go*, where nicknames are private), we can make one based on the TCG one. Since the TCG uses some type names that differ from the VG names, there will be some deviations, we also have to navigate around additional collisions. Here's the system I use:

[**N**]ormal
Fi[**R**]e
[**W**]ater
[**G**]rass
[**E**]lectric
[**i**]ce *(lower case because that avoids confusing it with lower case l)*
[**F**]ighting
P[**O**]ison
Gro[**U**]nd
F[**L**]ying
[**P**]sychic
[**B**]ug
Roc[**K**]
G[**H**]ost
Dr[**A**]gon
[**D**]ark
[**S**]teel
Fair[**Y**]

As you can see, there are quite a few collisions, and while many of the abbreviations that use a letter in the word attempt to take one that's at least rare (like Rock's K and Ground's U), it doesn't always work (Dragon, for instance, manages to have 3 letters another type starts with, one that fits Poison best because it's actually in there twice, and one that fits Fire best because it's the one used in the TCG, too). However, all in-word-letters are never at the start of a type, which is why Dragon's N was changed from the TCG version. This and L becoming Flying instead of Lightning (which is called Electric in the VG and makes much more sense as an E) are the only ones that don't mean the same thing as in the TCG version.

Comment: This is not "established"

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer And I clearly state so in the answer. The TCG one is established. Literally everyone is using it.

Comment: "there's no widely agreed upon similar system for the full type list we find in the video games". The one you "propose" is not established, and a minimal fraction of Pokémon players even knows about the TCG.

Comment: What is the TCG?

Comment: TCG = Trading Card Game

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Yes. "Widely agreed upon" is a synonym for "established". What's you point? The question is "is there one"? My answer is "there's none, but here's one you can used even though it's not established". Please explain to me why that's a worse answer than "there's none, and I'm not willing to give you one you can use even though it's not established".

Comment: J, Q, V, X, and Z are not present in any types, so the only letters unused by this list are C, M, and T.  This isn't standard by any means, but if OP is looking for a uniquely identifiable list of letters to distinguish the 18 Pokémon types, this is definitely a good baseline.  +1

Comment: @ChaseSandmann Thanks :) Yeah, there's not really a way around some creative tricks if only one letter is to be used. With 26 letters and 18 types, I was actually surprised there were so few cases where the system isn't intuitive (admittedly, being used to the TCG version and thus R and Y feeling intuitive). It's unlikely anyone will ever put much effort into making a standard system though, since it's useless in other Pokemon games and Go players often use unicode symbols. And even those are far from a standardized system.

Comment: @scenia Your answer is much better as it addresses both my literal question and the problem I was trying to solve with it.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no established abbreviation system for types.